# How to get rid of missing dependency warning of useEffect in React

Tags: react-hooks

I am getting a missing dependency warning error.
Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useSPices = () => {
    const [spices, setSpices] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/spices")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setSpices(data))

    });
    return [spices, setSpices];
}

export default useSPices;
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency array tells `useEffect` when to run:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do smth
}, [var1, var2 ...]);
```

Whenever any of the variables in that array (`var1` and so on) change, it causes the code inside the `useEffect` to execute. If you dont supply this array, the `useEffect` executes its code on **every** render.

You could do something like this:

```
function MyFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [url]);

  return [data];
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const data = MyFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  console.log(data[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data[0]).map((key) => (
        <div>
          {key} - {data[0][key] + ""}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`useEffect` is a tricky one to be honest with you. `useEffect` runs **after** every render (since you have no dependency array), and `setState` causes a re-render, so you have to be a bit careful when setting state from inside `useEffect`. Currently, in your code, what happens is:

1. `useEffect` runs
2. `setState` is executed, which causes a re-render
3. `useEffect` runs again because of the re-render

To avoid this, don't update things from inside the `useEffect` that would trigger the `useEffect` to re-run.

Here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-goldstine-jx1r81?file=/src/App.js:280-567

I see that you are returning the `setSpices` function, what is your goal? If you want `useSpices` to be a function for fetching stuff asynchronously, the returning just the `spices` will be enough, but I can't think of a reason of why you might want to return the `setSpices` function as well.